# Get height of ant design component using ref.current.clientHeight is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to detect the change in the height of an ant design `<Row>` component
However, when I added a reference to it and tried to get the `clientHeight` of `ref.current.clientHeight`, I get an undefined value

Any idea how can I get the height of an antd element?
I can add a parent wrapper to the `antd` component but I don't want to do that... I need to access the inner DOM of the component

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-gates-jq46u?file=/index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Card } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("height", ref?.current?.clientHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card title="Test" style={{ width: 300 }} ref={ref}>
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: could you include your code.

Comment: Attached a codesandbox link

Answer (score 1):

Since `Card` is a functional component and `antd` doesn't implement this component by `React.forwardRef`, actually you can't access the card dom element by passing ref, as an alternative you can set an `id` on the `Card` component and try to get the DOM node by `document.getElementById`, like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.getElementById('myCard');
    console.log("height", ref.current.clientHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card title="Test" style={{ width: 300 }} id="myCard">
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

another solution colud be, to assign the ref on the parent of `Card` component, like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("height", ref.current?.clientHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <Card title="Test" style={{ width: 300 }}>
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
        <p>Card content</p>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If I wrapped my `App` component with `React.forwardRef`, would this enable me to access the `ref.current.clientHeight`? Referencing this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: No, it couldn't help, because problem is that  `Card` component doesn't receive `ref` prop.